# It was a terribly difficult time for all of us. - adjectival preposition

Tags: grammar, prepositions, syntactic-analysis, parts-of-speech

> It was a terribly difficult time ***for all of us***.

In this sentence, what is the role of the prepositional phrase "for all of us"? I think it's adjectival and it modifies the noun "time."

Comment: It looks rather like the object of the adjective "difficult".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you fev =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it wasn't so a much a time for us, as that it was difficult for us. So it seems to me "for all of us" modifies "difficult."

Here's another similar question and answer: [How to tell which word a prepositional phrase is modifying?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/482541/how-to-tell-which-word-a-prepositional-phrase-is-modifying)

Comment: Thank you. I have asked the classic adjective question "which one?" to the word "time" and thought "time for all of us" is adjectival (which time? the time that is for all of us) but it's illogical it seems =).